# How to call delegates in different storyboard for different views in Tab Bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

[image: ScreenShot]
I have to implement coach marks in the beginning of the app and at the time of tutorial tab clicked. But when I tried to implement it the app the methods are not being called. Because of this, I am not able to proceed further.

```
- (id)initWithTuorialType:(TutorialType )type withDelegate:(id)delegate {
```

This method is not being called.

But when I create tutorialArray separately its get called in Tutorial Tab Bar only.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**TutorialVC.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef enum : NSInteger {
    Launch = 1,
    Learn
} TutorialType;

@protocol TutorialVCDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

- (void)didCompleteTutorial:(TutorialType)type;
@end


@interface TutorialVC : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

- (id)initWithTuorialType:(TutorialType )type withDelegate:(id)delegate;

@end
```

**TutorialVC.m**

```
#import "TutorialVC.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "HomeViewController.h"

@interface TutorialVC ()
{
    NSArray *tutorialArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
@property (nonatomic, assign)TutorialType tutorialType;
@property (nonatomic, weak)id delegate;

@end

@implementation TutorialVC

- (id)initWithTuorialType:(TutorialType )type withDelegate:(id)delegate {
    self = [super init];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Tutorial" bundle:nil];
    TutorialVC *tutorialViewController = (TutorialVC *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TutorialVC"];

    self = tutorialViewController;

    _tutorialType = type;
    _delegate = delegate;

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

    if(_tutorialType == Launch)
        tutorialArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"page1",@"page2",@"page3",@"page4",@"page5",@"page6",@"page7",@"page8",@"page9",@"page10",@"page11",@"page12", nil];
    else if(_tutorialType == Learn) {
        tutorialArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"page1",@"page2",@"page3",@"page4",@"page5",@"page6",@"page7",@"page8",@"page9",@"page10",@"page11",@"page12",nil];

    }

    tutorialArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 0;

    // tutorialArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"page1",@"page2",@"page3",@"page4",@"page5",@"page6",@"page7",@"page8",@"page9",@"page10",@"page11",@"page12",nil];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *recon = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGesture)];
    [recon setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recon];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeGesture)];
    [recon setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipe];

    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = tutorialArray.count;

    //NSLog(@"The array size is %@", tutorialArray);
    //NSLog(@"Array Count = %lu", (unsigned long)[tutorialArray count]);

    [self addTutorialScreen];
}
```

Comment: please make your question clear? what's your need

Comment: you mean.you have two storyboard right & you need to call another storyboard.. right

Comment: typedef enum : NSInteger {
    Launch = 1,
    Learn
} TutorialType;

These are the two condition on which my coach marks  should work but I am not able to call this method 
- (id)initWithTuorialType:(TutorialType )type withDelegate:(id)delegate {

Comment: i think your delegate is not set proper.

Comment: What I am doing wrong in it can u suggest.

Comment: first remove the app then check .....if not called then check delegate

Comment: Its not been called in the App also when i pass the condition. 
It works only when I define the array separately. i.e     // tutorialArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"page1",@"page2",@"page3",@"page4",@"page5",@"page6",@"page7",@"page8",@"page9",@"page10",@"page11",@"page12",nil];

I have commented that line u can see that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152001/discussion-between-chandan-anand-and-maulik-shah).

Comment: @ChandanAnand Does the answer solve your problem, please give feedback, thanks